# How do I get an element in a Svelte array using a value derived from a select element?

Tags: arrays, select, svelte

I have a list of users which I iterate over to populate a selection pull down but I need to use the selected user to pull their age from the array. I've bound value to the variable select but  I can't seem to get the value of users[id=select].age

```
<script lang="ts">
  import Users from './lib/Users.svelte';
const users = [
    {
      id:1,
      name: 'Andrew',
      age: '39',
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name: 'David',
      price: '80',
    },


  ] as User[];
  let selected = '0';
  let age = users[0].age;
</script>
<div class="min-h-screen bg-slate-800 text-white">
  <main class="max-w-screen-rs mx-auto">

    <select bind:value={selected} class="bg-green-800 text-white" id="userSelect" name="userSelect" size="1">
       <option value="0" selected="selected">Select a user</option>
        {#each users as user}
        <option value={user.id}>{user.category}</option>
        {/each}
    </select>
</main>
</div>
```

I've tried the following
let age = users[id={selected}].age;

but to no avail. I have output to the console the value of selected and it is updating that value but if I try and use it as defined above I just get a blank page no error message nothing just code that won't render

Comment: the same way you would in regular javascript, `users.find(u => u.id == selected)`

Comment: that won't find the age value though will it?

Comment: it gives you the first object (if any) that matches the predicate, just add `.age` afterwards or whatever you like

Comment: it's just stopping rendering the code instead when I try
let age = users.find(u => u.id == selected).age;

Comment: I have made some progress at least it works if I hard code a value instead of trying to use the value derived from the selection box but that isn't what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependent statements need to be made reactive via [`$:`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive)  in Svelte 3/4:

```js
$: age = users[selected]?.age;
```

(`?.` prevents errors if no user is selected, it will fall back to `undefined`.)